# How internally works packagesToScan in Spring?

Tags: spring

In Spring, Hibernate/JPA Configuration, to load all entities we are using **packagesToScan** property. How this one internally works and loads all entities.

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <array>
        <value>com.test1</value>
        <value>com.test2</value>
    </array>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA implementation scans all classes within the identified packages and checks them if they are annotated as entity using @Entity on class level, if the class annotated then it is an entity class, otherwise it will be ignored.

Comment: Here i have two questions.

Comment: 1. How internally loads all classes in a Particular package.

Comment: 2. How it will look class is annotated with @Entity annotation.

Comment: They use reflection to load the needed classes and check if they annotated by a specific annotation. for more details read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful

Comment: so if you annotate a class using the @Entity tag, then you don't need to add the the packagesToScan in the XML?